# how to access usb Mass Storage Device in uclinux...?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uclinux

I have got the kernel log it says about usb but how can access it . there is no device registration in /dev ..? how access this..?
and configured and anabledin kernel

Under "Device Drivers"

Under "USB Support"
        Enable "USB Mass Storage Support"
        (Optionally) Enable "USB Mass Storage verbose debug"
    Under "SCSI device support -->"
        Enable "SCSI disk support"

```
usb 1-2: new full speed USB device using lpc178x-ohci and address 2         
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=1000                    
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3               
usb 1-2: Product: Mass Storage Device                                           
usb 1-2: Manufacturer: JetFlash                                                 
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 74O2LC2HD514SCME
```

Answer (score -1):

@Amar, in the kernel log, will find the information regarding where the plugged in USB mass storage device is attached to in the filesystem for ex: it can be either **sda or sdb or sdc**. Check and use mount command to mount USB mass storage `sudo mount /dev/sd* <Path where you want to mount USB device>` and after you can access USB mass storage. Below is the kernel log information on where the USB mass storage is attached to

```
[85508.500115] usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[85509.110370] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[85509.112895] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[85509.113486] usb-storage: device found at 3
[85509.113487] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[85514.128615] usb-storage: device scan complete
[85514.137855] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access Generic- Compact Flash 1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[85514.146766] scsi 4:0:0:1: Direct-Access Multiple Flash Reader  1.05 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[85514.148945] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[85514.149018] sd 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[85514.549761] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[85514.558770] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] 31116288 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[85514.586964] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[85514.586966] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[85514.586968] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[85514.711875] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[85514.711880]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3 sdc4
[85514.808220] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[85514.808224] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

In this case mount either /dev/sdc1 or /dev/sdc2 or /dev/sdc3 or /dev/sdc4 partition 
depending on which partition you are interested in.

Comment: yes I have the information about usb like sda in kernel log but after booting there is no sda in /dev directory. how to get it ..?

Comment: Ok after booting, is your usb mass storage device plugged in? if plugged in, remove and try to plug in once again. Before plunging in clear all the dmesg, sudo dmesg -c > /dev/null.

Comment: after manual I created a nod by using mknod when i executed mount /dev/sda1 /media it says

"mount: can't read '/etc/fstab': No such file or directory" what is the cause for this error..?

Comment: You should not manually create device node. Attach kernel log when you plugin usb mass storage and kernel log after re-booting.

Comment: @GauthamKantharaju - you mistaken.  Device nodes are not created by the kernel, they must be created either manually or by a userspace daemon.  Modern desktop systems typically use a daemon, but small / older embedded systems often do not, requiring that it either be done manually or by manually adding it to the system startup scripts.

Comment: @Chris, I do understand that we need to manually create device node on embedded platform by getting the major no while loading the kernel module. Nowadays device node are created dynamically when kernel module are loaded using newer driver registration API's. But in this case it's a mass storage device, when plugged in usb driver will detect and attach, as in the above example, we just have to mount it on to our file system for ex: mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/tmp and read or write from/to /mnt/tmp

Comment: @GauthamKantharaju - no, you are assuming the operation of **userspace** daemons which are likely not present on this simple system.  In their absence, the nodes must be created explicitly, **before** one can even think about mounting it.

Comment: @Chris, ok but for creating a device node we need major and minor no details, where will we getting these details from?

Comment: On an embedded system, it may be reasonable to *assume*, at least to proactively create the possibilities.  What is actually present can be determined from /proc/partitions (if enabled), notified through dbus (if enabled), manually parsed out of dmesg by the operator, etc - there's a wider range of methods in use on embedded systems than what is currently favored on the desktop.